# Initializing main function from Matlab Coder

Tags: c++, matlab, command-line-arguments

I created a C++ program through Matlab coder called implicit_enumeration.cpp which takes a matrix A and a vector b as input and returns a vector zstar and a probability value Vstar. I am now struggling to initialize the main function:

```
// Include Files
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "implicit_enumeration.h"
#include "main.h"

// Function Declarations
static void argInit_4x1_real_T(double result[4]);
static void argInit_4x9_real_T(double result[36]);
static void main_implicit_enumeration();

// Function Definitions

static void argInit_4x1_real_T(double result[4])
{
    int idx0;

    // Loop over the array to initialize each element.
    for (idx0 = 0; idx0 < 4; idx0++) {
        // Set the value of the array element.
        // Change this value to the value that the application requires.
        result[idx0] = 1;
    }
}

static void argInit_4x9_real_T(double result[36])
{
    int idx0;
    int idx1;

    // Loop over the array to initialize each element.
    for (idx0 = 0; idx0 < 4; idx0++) {
        for (idx1 = 0; idx1 < 9; idx1++) {
            // Set the value of the array element.
            // Change this value to the value that the application requires.
            if (idx0 == 0) {
                if (idx1 == 0) { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 1; }
                else if (idx1 == 1) { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 1; }
                else { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 0; }
            }
            else if (idx0 == 1) {
                if (idx1 == 2) { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 1; }
                else if (idx1 == 3) { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 1; }
                else if (idx1 == 4) { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 1; }
                else { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 0; }
            }
            else if (idx0 == 2) {
                if (idx1 == 5) { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 1; }
                else { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 0; }
            }
            else {
                if (idx1 == 6) { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 1; }
                else if (idx1 == 7) { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 1; }
                else if (idx1 == 8) { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 1; }
                else { result[idx0 + (idx1 << 2)] = 0; }
            }
        }
    }
}

static void main_implicit_enumeration()
{
    double dv0[36];
    double dv1[4];
    double zstar[9];
    double Vstar;

    // Initialize function 'implicit_enumeration' input arguments.
    // Initialize function input argument 'A'.
    // Initialize function input argument 'b'.
    // Call the entry-point 'implicit_enumeration'.
    argInit_4x9_real_T(dv0);
    argInit_4x1_real_T(dv1);
    implicit_enumeration(dv0, dv1, zstar, &Vstar);
}

int main(int argc, const char * const argv[])
{
    // Initialize the application.
    // You do not need to do this more than one time.
    // Invoke the entry-point functions.
    // You can call entry-point functions multiple times.
    main_implicit_enumeration();
    return 0;
}
```

Specifically, I am wondering how to initialize argv[] as a matrix A and a vector b. Is it necessary to set the command arguments even though I already initialized the matrix A and the vector b through the functions argInit_4x9_real_T() and argInit_4x1_real_T()? If yes, how to include a matrix and a vector as command arguments? The examples I checked always show single integer or real values, but not matrix or vectors.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `argv[]` isnt used in the code. Not clear what you mean with "initialize the main function"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are mostly done.

In main(int argc, const char * const argv[]):
argc is the number of of command line arguments, argv contains these command line arguments.

Example:
If you call `test.ext something`, argc is 2, argv[0] is "test.exe", argv[1] is "something".

Your initialization is done in main_implicit_enumeration()

- dv0 is you matrix A (4*9 Matrix -> 36 elements), and it is
  initialized in argInit_4x9_real_T()
- dv1 is your vector b (4 Vector -> 4 elements), and it is initialized in argInit_4x1_real_T
- zstar is the return vector
- Vstar the skalar return

Question is: How do you want to pass values to your program? Load values from a file? Use a format like `test.ext A=1,2,3;4,5,6 b=8,9` ?